# Hibernate is adding UTC offset for every db update

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, jdbc

I have a mySQL db with columns of the time type. I'm using Hibernate for ORM. The Hibernate time type is `java.sql.Time`. I'm noticing that whenever I update a column in the table,  the time value also gets updated. The UTC offset gets added for every update. For example, consider a table with a `name`(string) and a time field. Let the initial db entry for time be "00:00:00". Now if I update `name` using an endpoint + Hibernate query, the time value gets updated to "05:00:00" in the db. If I update `name` again, the time value becomes "10:00:00" in the db. My time zone is EST by the way. Why is this happening and how can I prevent it?

Setting `hibernate.jdbc.time_zone: UTC` fixes the problem but I'd like some more information behind this behavior.

Comment: What you're saying makes no sense.  "Time" is physically stored in mySql as a "number" with respect to an "epoch" - it's completely agnostic as to "time zone".  So where are you seeing these values?  Who did the initial "insert"?  An endpoint in your web app, which invoked a Hibernate "save()"?  What do you see when you query the value (e.g. "select" in the mySql CLI)?  Now who does the "update"?  Also an endpoint in your web app?  What does mySql CLI "select" return immediately after the update?  Did the time really "jump ahead 5 hours"????

Comment: Yes, all the updates were done using an endpoint in my app which invoked a Hibernate save() or update(). I use Postman for testing my endpoints. I see the updated time values in the response in Postman. Apparently it has to do something with the timezone of my JDBC connection defaulting to my server's timezone, i.e., EST.

Comment: Postman shows JSON/Javascript, JS represents time in ISO 8601 format, and ISO 8601 respects time zone.  Q: Can you query the database from the MySql CLI?  Q: Can you query immediately after an insert, and immediately after an update?  Q: Do you see "jump ahead 5 hours"?  The answer should be "No!".  You *will* see one or the other time zone (e.g. the mySql server's time zone).  Once you've established that much, then we can figure out how you'd like your app to behave.  KEY POINT: What you "see" (how the time is represented) is DIFFERENT from "what's stored in the database".

Comment: There's no time jump if I query the time from mySQL. If I post a time of "00:00:00" via Postman, "05:00:00" gets stored in mySQL. When I query directly from MySQL CLI, I get "05:00:00" as the time. Again, when I get the same data via the endpoint, I'd expect "00:00:00" to be returned, but "05:00:00" gets returned. This problem exists only for the TIME field and not datetime fields...probably because tz info isn't stored in time. After adding `hibernate.jdbc.time_zone: UTC`, the time gets returned correctly as "00:00:00".

Comment: OK: then explicitly setting `hibernate.jdbc.time_zone` is probably the best solution. You're correct: TZ *isn't* stored with "time".  REFERENCE: https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tips-whats-the-best-way-to-persist-a-zoneddatetime.  Silly question: since timezones *are* an issue ... and since storing as a "datetime" (or "timestamp") would mitigate the problem ... is there any chance you could simply change the field to a "datetime"?

Comment: No - time is the best data type for my use case. Do you know why setting `hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=UTC` solved the problem?

Comment: Q: Do you know why setting hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=UTC solved the problem?  A: Please read (or view) these links, and post back if you have any additional questions:  https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-jpa-date-and-time/ and https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tips-whats-the-best-way-to-persist-a-zoneddatetime/  PS: Please do consider "datetime" (or "timestamp").  At a minimum please consider using Java8 time.* classes, instead of java.sql.time...

Comment: Question: Isn't adding `?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false` to the jdbc url suffice? Why do I have to add the above and `hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=UTC`?

Comment: I'm no longer sure what parts  you truly don't understand ... vs. what parts you merely "don't like" :(  In any case, please do read the links I cited (as well as any other "hibernate" resource).  And no: I'm not familar with that sesquipedialian JDBC URL ... but if it works for you - great!  Go for it :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you Tried tot User LocalTime instead of java.sql.Time?

LocalTime  should handle all the TimeZone pitfalls foe you.

Java.sql.Time is not TimeZone aware.

Comment: Unfortunately, LocalTime also causes the same problem.